# Android: should we pass context to domain layer?

Tags: android, design-patterns, architecture, android-context

I am trying to use the [architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/domain-layer) recommended by android in a project and I was wondering if it is legitimate and recommended to pass the `context` to the domain layer through the `AndroidViewModel`:

```
class PlacesViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val app = application
    val domainLayer = DomainLayer()

    fun example() {
        domainLayer(app)
    }
}
```

Comment: In theory the domain should be agnostic to the system, so it is not recommended to pass it... but the question is, why do you need the app context in the domain?

Comment: @ManuelMato When an object is inserted, modified or deleted in the database, I have to decide whether to insert or delete an alarm through the alarm manager (I have opened a specific [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72839727/android-how-to-set-a-broadcast-receiver-in-a-layered-architecture) for this question). Reading the article it did not seem appropriate to insert this action in the UI layer since it does not change the state of the UI nor in the data layer since here I simply have to store the selected time and days of the week.

Comment: Then, if you need the AlarmManager , you should to inject the AlarmManager in the UseCase, but no the context in the viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

You can get that from `application` as you mentioned : `application.applicationContext`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).